# MySQL query generating different results on different servers

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I've set up a custom `ORDER BY` clause for a query that The Events Calendar using the `posts_where` filter. It looks like this:

```
// $compareTimeToday is the result of strtotime('today');
// $compareTimeTomorrow is the result of strtotime('tomorrow');
// MIN(wp_postmeta.meta_value) ultimately fetches the _EventStartDate 
// post meta, which is in MySQL format (YYYY-MM-DD H:i:s)
// This query forces events happening today ahead of events that are
// happening today but are multi-day and started in the past
$orderby = "CASE
            WHEN MIN(wp_postmeta.meta_value) BETWEEN FROM_UNIXTIME($compareTimeToday) AND FROM_UNIXTIME($compareTimeTomorrow)
              THEN 1
            ELSE 2
          END ASC, " . $orderby;
```

Things seemed fine, but the client added a couple of events that did manage to mess this up. After the client added those events, I pulled a copy of the database, so **my local database matches the staging on exactly**.

On my local environment, here is the result:

[image]

So events that started today, and then all other upcoming events in order of date (starting with an event that started in August, in this case). **At the bottom of that list is a multi-day event that started yesterday and goes through November, and it's the last event on the site. You'll see it in the next screenshot.**

Here's what the staging environment shows:

[image]

The item from the bottom of the list is now at the top (undesired).

Why am I getting different results between the two machines on the exact same codeset and database?

Local PHP: 7.1.0
Local MySQL: 5.7.16

Staging PHP: 7.0.2
Staging MySQL: 5.7.18

**If I dump `date_default_timezone_get()` on them, they both show plain 'ol UTC.**

Any idea why I'm getting different results between the two?

**EDIT:** The client's server management team has told me that the staging server itself may be in Eastern time, despite PHP spitting out UTC. If the PHP variables going into the query and the contents of the database are all the same between the two environments, would this matter?

Comment: Wouldn’t you rather just have a (consistently) working query?

Comment: I don't have much experience at all with MySQL etc. but it seems like your test event has a time associated with it but those others don't? Also not sure why you can't just order events by start date alone?

Comment: Surely this is working fine and your staging area just has a test event added called 'Multiday Test Event', and your live version doesn't.

Comment: What is the timezone of the database on the two servers?

Comment: @ColinGell But the multiday event shouldn't be first, because it's not starting today.

Comment: @ethanc how are you using your $orderby variable in your code - where is it outputting too, and is it being used correctly in your sql

Comment: @Barmar actually, we have no idea what is the `MIN(wp_postmeta.meta_value)` value for the multiday event. The question does not have the data from the database. The mysql servers may be in diferent timezones affecting the timestamp values within mysql.

Comment: @Shadow From the context, I interpreted it as the start date shown in the output.

Comment: @Barmar I am not saying that your interpretation is incorrect, merely pointing out, that it is only an assumption at the moment. We do not really know. The mysql servers may be in different timezones affecting the evaluation of a timestamp. Without seeing the actual data and understanding the data types, it is impossible to answer this question. Note, the multiday event does not even show up in the 1st screnshot.

Comment: @Shadow True, I gave the OP a little benefit of the doubt. I think the most likely answer is timezone related, but it could be that the data changed after he copied.

Comment: @Shadow Can't ping everyone, but the comments above the code clearly state that `MIN(wp_postmeta.meta_value)` grabs the event start date from the DB, in Y-m-d H:i:s. Question also states that PHP timezones are both UTC. Given that consistency plus the databases having the exact same content, doesn't seem like a timezone issue, but could be?

Comment: @ColinGell question states that both databases are exactly the same. The 'Multiday Test Event' is on both, but in the correct order (at the bottom and out of the screenshot) on the local one.

Comment: @EthanC and how would I know what is the even start date on the screenshots? How would I know what value is fetched from the db in that query? And you seem to forget that mysql also has timezone setting, not just php.

Comment: @Shadow didn't know MySQL had a timezone setting. Is that set independently from the server? As far as what value is fetched from the DB, the start date is in the screenshots, but I honestly wasn't sure it mattered, since I do know that the databases are identical.

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/time-zone-support.html

Comment: @EthanC if everything is exactly the same then and all the code is the same, the only difference is where the data is being input from? perhaps replicate the steps the client took to input the data and Shadow's comments do seem valid

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @Shadow for the right direction. MySQL timezone was indeed `America\New York` it seems and was running some conversions on `FROM_UNIXTIME`, while dev is plain 'ol UTC

This is further complicated in that WordPress allows you to set a timezone in the admin, but doesn't force that at the PHP level, and further operates assuming UTC, so you have to set and then reset the timezone when the admin setting is important.